# CSS tag element not recognized in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a simple Javascript program that will take elements from an array and display them inline.  The problem is the Javascript I'm using is not recognizing the CSS associated with the

tags for displaying the elements inline and thus displaying the elements in the array from the  CSS.

Javascript:

```
var data = ["David Cameron", "Tony Blair", "Gordon Brown"];

var result = '';

for (var i = 0; i<=2; i++) {
result+='<div id= quizcontain>' +'<p>'+data[i]+'</p>'+'</div>'
}

document.getElementById('quizcontain').innerHTML+= result;
```

CSS:

```
#quizcontain p {
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/RrZUq/1/
The problem was, that You had multiple DIV with same id...

```
var data = ["David Cameron", "Tony Blair", "Gordon Brown"];
var result = '';
for (var i = 0; i<=2; i++) {
    result += '<p>'+data[i]+'</p>';
}
document.getElementById('quizcontain').innerHTML+= result;
```

Comment: Changed my code so that the div was using 'id' instead of 'class'.  Works fine now,  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i<=2; i++) {
    result += '<div id="quizcontain"><p>'+data[i]+'</p></div>'
}
```

Comment: I originally wrote the code this way and the array elements are still being displayed in a block format.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to put the id in quotes

```
<div id="quizcontain"'
```

[css-ids](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly you use want the results to be inline? Right now you are adding the `<div id="quizcontain">` inside of the same one, so either remove`<div id="quizcontain">` from your result variable or target just `#quizcontain` in your CSS

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L3pMG/7/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be in the way you defined id attribute. It should be `<div id="quizcontain">`

By the way, ideally you should not use id attribute for repetitive elemant in the html document. You can use class attribute instead

Comment: You should not use duplicate IDs at all. http://validator.w3.org would complain as well

Answer (score 0):

your code is messy: you add too many divs. Supposing you already have a `<div id="quizcontain" />` somewhere, juste use this:

```
var data = ["David Cameron", "Tony Blair", "Gordon Brown"];

var result = '';

for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    result += '<p>' + data[i] + '</p>';
}

document.getElementById('quizcontain').innerHTML += result;
```